# How to call specific rows from a table in MySQL ? (see the case)

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

The website is intended for users to enable them joining the courses and posting their updates to these courses and also receiving the course updates made by others (imagen courses as Groups in Facebook but in my website users post updates ONLY through the courses)

When the user login to the website, he is suposed to see all the updates in the courses he already is joined in.

I have many tables in MySQL :

- 'updates' which have these attributes (id, account_id,course_id,datetime,content) noticing that course and account ID's are foreign keys..
- 'courses' which have these attributes (id,name,..)
- 'accounts' which have these attributes (id,full_name,...)
- 'accounts_courses_relationship' (account_id,course_id) , to map the relations between users and courses.

I have tried many times but the only thing I get is to show all the updates for all courses without excluding the updates from the courses that user isn't a member of, as follow:

```
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT datetime, content
    FROM updates 
    WHERE account_id != {$account_id}
    ORDER BY datetime DESC
    LIMIT 10";
```

So, How to exclude the updates from these courses?

Note: don't forget that all mappings between users and courses are registered in a table shown above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work

```
select * 
from updates u
join accounts_courses_relationship r on u.courseid = r.courseid
where r.account_id = {$account_id}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well i might be not seeing your problem it but how about

```
SELECT ... FROM updates where account_id = {$account_id}
```

Would't this select all updates for the current user and therefore all the updates the user is interested in?

Comment: in the home, i'm interested in the updates of others in my courses, not interested in my updates.

Answer (score 1):

You have to inner join the updates and courses and accounts and accounts_courses tables.

```
       select acr.accountid, acr.courseid, courses.name, accounts.fullname, updates.datetime, updates.content
       from accounts_courses_relationship acr
       inner join courses on acr.courseid=courses.courseid
       inner join accounts on acr.accountid = accounts.accountid
       inner join updates on updates.accountid= accounts.accountid and updates.courseid=courses.courseid
       where accountid = {?}
       order by updates.datetime desc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in seeing updates to courses from other users (not you) and you're a registered user of those courses:

```
SELECT DISTINCT datetime, content
FROM updates 
WHERE account_id != {$account_id}
    and course_id in (select acr.course_id from accounts_courses_relationship acr where acr.account_id = updates.account_id)
ORDER BY datetime DESC
LIMIT 10
```